# Need to Find dynamically changing integer from string based text file

Tags: python

I need to convert or fetch values of integers at the end of the string from following 4 string from a text file .

Integer values at the last of each string constantly change,  which is a problem here. How can i implement it through regex?

```
string1 = ('Port A Rx frames:\t', '1003')

string2 = ('Port B Rx frames:\t', '1000')

string3 = ('Tx FrameCount :', 'Port A', '1001')

string4 = ('Tx FrameCount :', 'Port B', '1001')
```

I tried regular expression but it is not working:

```
import os
import re

f1 = open("C:/path/Desktop/set_initial.txt")

s1 = "('Port A Rx frames:\t', '1003')"
s2 = "('Port B Rx frames:\t', '1000')"
s3 = "('Tx FrameCount A :', 'txstreamresults', '1001')"
s4 = "('Tx FrameCount B :', 'txstreamresults', '1001')"

for line in f1:

    a = int(re.search(r'\d+', s1).group())
    b = int(re.search(r'\d+', s2).group())
    c = int(re.search(r'\d+', s3).group())
    d = int(re.search(r'\d+', s4).group())

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

expected output :

```
1003
1000
1001 
1001
```

observed output but i have kept above 4 strings as static however integer values at last of each string will dynamically change:

```
1003 
1000 
1001 
1001
```

Comment: Running your code results in your expected output being outputted. Can you elaborate the problem more please?

Comment: @lahsuk : I need to fetch the  integer dynamically for above for strings from a text file.

Comment: @lahsuk :  but the integers in these string dynamically change in the text file always . So how to fetch them from text file . Rest of the string is constant

Comment: How do your `set_initial.txt` change? Each loop? Each few seconds? Each hour? or Each what? You need to define it then read your file right after that changed.

Comment: @DiwakarSHARMA It seems all your string variables are tuples of different length as per the examples given by you: like `string1 `, `string2`, etc. So, why not access your preferred integers as `int(string1[-1])`, `int(string2[-1])`. Check if this works for you. It doesn't require regular expression.

Comment: @LêTưThành I have, string3 = ('Tx FrameCount :', 'Port A', '1001')
string3[-1] gives what he desires: the last integer in the tuple. And I am trying to understand his requirement too. I used the first set of examples he has given: `string1 = ('Port A Rx frames:\t', '1003')`

Comment: @a_r, his require is read from a text file.

Comment: Set_initial text file changes with run of python traffic generator script which generate these 4 strings

Comment: Guys they are string not tuples , text appear with brackets , please consider them as string not tuples

Comment: Does the below answer meet your requirement, @DiwakarSHARMA ?

Comment: Guys 1001 ,1000, 1000 which are mentioned in the text file strings at the very end change with every run of python script which generate a this text file. My goal is to fetch these values dynamically everytime

Comment: I will check and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need.

```
import re
with open("C:/path/Desktop/set_initial.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip():
            a = re.search(r'(\d+)', line)
            if a:
                print(int(a.group(1)))
```

Comment: Thanks guys , brilliant answer by all of you  . Thanks for such a great support guys

Answer (score 1):

Taking that your variables like `s1`, `s2` etc are taken directly from a text file, and it appears exactly as you have presented these variable's values in your code, eg:

```
s2 = "('Port B Rx frames:\t', '1000')"
s3 = "('Tx FrameCount A :', 'txstreamresults', '1001')"
s4 = "('Tx FrameCount B :', 'txstreamresults', '1001')"
```

You can use the following to get the 4 digit integer:

```
all_numbers = []
with open('number.txt', 'r') as opened_file:
    for line in opened_file:
        number = ''
        for e in line.split(',')[-1]:
            if e.isdigit():
                number = number+e
        value = int(number)
        all_numbers.append(value)
all_numbers
```

The variable `value` has the integer digit like 1001, 1000 etc. If you want to get the string form, ignore the conversion at `value = int(number)`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you catch my idea about your issue.

```py
import re
fname = "/path/to/set_initial.txt"
check_update = True
while check_update:
    readfile = open(fname, 'r').read()  # " a, 123 \n b, 234 \n c, 345"
    list_of_numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', readfile)  # ['123', '234', '345']
    if updating_file:   # traffic generator script run  <== MOST IMPORTANT
        check_update = True
    else:
        check_update = False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.findall('\d{4}', s)` to get a list of **4-digit** strings in `s`. The list could then be just joined or use index to get the first (*and assuming the only result*) since there is only one 4-digit number in each string.

## Example

### Option-1

```py
import re

s1 = "('Port A Rx frames:\t', '1003')"
s2 = "('Port B Rx frames:\t', '1000')"
s3 = "('Tx FrameCount A :', 'txstreamresults', '1001')"
s4 = "('Tx FrameCount B :', 'txstreamresults', '1001')"

ss = [s1, s2, s3, s4]

[''.join(re.findall('\d{4}', s)) for s in ss]
```

#### Output

```
['1003', '1000', '1001', '1001']
```

### Option-2

You join all strings together (assuming you could read the entire file as a single string)

```py
re.findall('\d{4}', '\n'.join(ss))
```

#### Output

```
['1003', '1000', '1001', '1001']
```